# Find the group name that has the maximum difference within groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
Suppose we have a dataframe like this:

name   value
'hi'    1
'hi'    2
'hi'    3
'hello' 5
'hello' 6 
'hello'  8
```

How can we find the group name that has the maximum within groups difference?

(In the example above, the maximum within groups difference is 3, so how to select the 'hello' from the name column?)

Comment: Just want to make it clear, the only thing I want to get from this data frame is the single string 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello'], 'value':[1,2,3,5,6,8]})
```

Use groupby to compute min and max value and the difference, and sort the difference values.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('name').agg('value').max() - df.groupby('name').agg('value').min()).sort_values(by='value')
```

Extracting the string only that has the largest difference:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('name').agg('value').max() - df.groupby('name').agg('value').min()).sort_values(by='value', ascending=False).index[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `apply(np.ptp)` and use `idxmax()`:

```
name_with_max_var = df.groupby('name')['value'].apply(np.ptp).idxmax()

df[df.name == name_with_max_var]
```

Output:

```
      name  value
3  'hello'      5
4  'hello'      6
5  'hello'      8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a single string like ths:

```
df.groupby('name')['value'].agg(np.ptp).idxmax()
```

Output:

```
"'hello'"
```

***Details:***

`groupby` name and the `agg`regate using `np.ptp` then select the index with the maximum value.

---

You can do it this way:

```
df.assign(diff = df.groupby('name')['value']
                   .transform(np.ptp))\
  .query('diff == diff.max()')
```

Output:

```
      name  value  diff
3  'hello'      5     3
4  'hello'      6     3
5  'hello'      8     3
```

***Details:***

Use `groupby` and `transform` to find the differnce use [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html), assign that value, as diff to every records, then `query` the dataframe to find where diff is equal to max diff.